# Magento: Get min. and max. price for a product (from associated products attributes price configuration)

Tags: php, magento

I try to get minimum and maximum price for a configurable product using its attributes. For example; I have defined prices for all associated products of Shoe XYZ (shoe_xyz_4 / size 4: $99, shoe_xyz_5 / size 5: $109, etc) and I want to display a price '$99—$109'.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score -3):

You can call it as an array like this:

```
$_maximumPriceValue =$_product[max_price];
```